# ScrollView not working ios

Tags: uiscrollview, swift3.2

My ScrollView contains a container view, which in turn has a textView whose height depends on the content and is dynamic.I have enabled the scroll for textview but it doesn't seem to work.I tried to set the content size of scroll view even in viewDidLayouts also, but that also doesn't work.
The code is as below:

```
import UIKit

class DiaryViewViewController: UIViewController, UITextViewDelegate, UIScrollViewDelegate, TagListViewDelegate {

var scrollView: UIScrollView!
var containerView = UIView()
let diaryDate = UITextView()
var tagListView: TagListView!
var assets: [DKAsset]?
var diaryEntryText = UITextView()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    self.scrollView = UIScrollView()
    self.scrollView.delegate = self
    containerView = UIView()
    self.scrollView.delegate = self
    scrollView.isDirectionalLockEnabled = true
    containerView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

    //to fetch height of screen
    let screenSize = UIScreen.main.bounds
    let width = screenSize.width
    let height = screenSize.height


    //Top Bar
    let topBar = UIView(frame:CGRect(x: 0,y: 0, width: width, height: 60))
    topBar.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
    topBar.layer.shadowColor = UIColor.gray.cgColor
    topBar.layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: 0, height: 3)
    topBar.layer.shadowOpacity = 1
    topBar.layer.masksToBounds = false
    topBar.layer.shadowRadius = 8.0;
    topBar.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

    //Label - Title
    let titleLabel = UILabel(frame:CGRect(x: width * 0.3, y: 13, width: width * 0.55, height: 40))
    titleLabel.text = "23 December 2018"
    titleLabel.contentMode = UIViewContentMode.center
    //include all in view
    topBar.addSubview(titleLabel)

    containerView.addSubview(topBar)

    let contentSize = diaryEntryText.sizeThatFits(diaryEntryText.bounds.size)
    diaryEntryText.text = "------Lorem ipsum dolor sit er elit lamet, consectetaur cillium adipisicing pecu, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. Nam liber te conscient to factor tum poen legum odioque civiuda.Lorem ipsum dolor sit er elit lamet, consectetaur cillium adipisicing pecu, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. Nam liber te conscient to factor tum poen legum odioque civiuda.Lorem ipsum dolor sit er elit lamet, consectetaur cillium adipisicing pecu, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur  magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. Nam liber te conscient to factor tum poen legum odioque civiudaLorem ipsum dolor sit er elit lamet, consectetaur cillium adipisicing pecu, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. erunt mollit anim id est laborum. Nam liber te conscient to factor tum poen legum odioque civiudaLorem ipsum dolor sit er elit lamet, consectetaur cillium adipisicing pecu, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. Nam liber te conscient to factor tum poen legum odioque civiuda.Lorem ipsum dolor sit er elit lamet, consectetaur cillium adipisicing pecu, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. Nam liber te conscient to factor tum poen legum odioque civiuda.Lorem ipsum dolor sit er elit lamet, consectetaur cillium adipisicing pecu, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua., uda.-----------------"
    diaryEntryText.frame.size.width = self.view.frame.width - 40
    diaryEntryText.frame.size.height = contentSize.height
    diaryEntryText.frame = CGRect(x:20, y:80, width:self.view.frame.width - 2, height:contentSize.height)
    diaryEntryText.isScrollEnabled = true
    diaryEntryText.textAlignment = .justified

    containerView.addSubview(diaryEntryText)

    let fixedWidthText = self.view.frame.width - 40
    diaryEntryText.sizeThatFits(CGSize(width: fixedWidthText, height: CGFloat.greatestFiniteMagnitude))
    let newSizeText = diaryEntryText.sizeThatFits(CGSize(width: fixedWidthText, height: CGFloat.greatestFiniteMagnitude))
    var newFrameText = diaryEntryText.frame
    newFrameText.size = CGSize(width: max(newSizeText.width, fixedWidthText), height: newSizeText.height)
    diaryEntryText.frame = newFrameText

    self.tagListView = TagListView()
    tagListView.delegate = self
    let contentSizeTag = tagListView.frame.size.height
    let yTag = newSizeText.height + 10 + 80

    var tagFrame = self.tagListView.frame
    tagFrame.size.width = self.view.frame.width-2
    tagFrame.size.height = contentSizeTag
    tagFrame.origin.x = 20
    tagFrame.origin.y = yTag
    tagListView.frame = tagFrame
    let tagArrayList = ["happy","enjoy","try"]
    for element in tagArrayList {
        tagListView.addTag(element)
    }
    containerView.addSubview(tagListView)

    let fixedWidthTag = self.view.frame.width - 40
    tagListView.sizeThatFits(CGSize(width: fixedWidthTag, height: CGFloat.greatestFiniteMagnitude))
    let newSizeTag = diaryEntryText.sizeThatFits(CGSize(width: fixedWidthTag, height: CGFloat.greatestFiniteMagnitude))
    var newFrameTag = tagListView.frame
    newFrameTag.size = CGSize(width: max(newSizeTag.width, fixedWidthTag), height: newSizeTag.height)
    tagListView.frame = newFrameTag

    let contentSizeDate = diaryDate.frame.size.height
    let yDate = yTag + 20
    diaryDate.text = "HSR Layout, Bangalore"
    diaryDate.frame = CGRect(x: 20, y: yDate, width: self.view.frame.width - 2, height:contentSizeTag+20)
    diaryDate.textColor = UIColor.cyan

    containerView.addSubview(diaryDate)

     scrollView.addSubview(containerView)
    self.view.addSubview(scrollView)


    if #available(iOS 11.0, *) {

        let top = NSLayoutConstraint.init(item: containerView, attribute: .top, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: self.view.safeAreaLayoutGuide, attribute: .top, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 0.0)
        let leading = NSLayoutConstraint.init(item: containerView, attribute: .leading, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: self.view, attribute: .leading, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 0.0)
        let trailing = NSLayoutConstraint.init(item: containerView, attribute: .trailing, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: self.view, attribute: .trailing, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 0.0)
        let height = NSLayoutConstraint.init(item: containerView, attribute: .height, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: nil, attribute: .notAnAttribute, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 60.0)

        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([top, leading, trailing, height])

    } else {
        // Fallback on earlier versions
    }

    self.scrollView.contentSize = CGSize(width: self.view.frame.size.width, height: yDate + contentSizeDate)

}


override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {

    super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()
    scrollView.frame = view.bounds
    containerView.frame = CGRect(x:0, y:0, width:scrollView.contentSize.width, height:scrollView.contentSize.height)

 /* I tried using this, but doesn't seem to work 

 let newSizeText = diaryEntryText.sizeThatFits(CGSize(width: self.view.frame.width - 40, height: CGFloat.greatestFiniteMagnitude))
    let yTag = newSizeText.height + 10 + 80
    let yDate = yTag + 20
    let contentSizeDate = diaryDate.frame.size.height

    self.scrollView.contentSize = CGSize(width: self.view.frame.size.width, height: yDate + contentSizeDate)
   */

}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}
}
```

Comment: What are you trying to achieve and what do you currently get?

Comment: If diaryText.text increases, then I want it to scroll automatically.But that doesn't occurs.

Answer (score 0):

You're missing the following properties:

**Swift 4.0**

```
diaryDate.showsVerticalScrollIndicator = true
diaryDate.isScrollEnabled = true
diaryDate.scrollRangeToVisible(NSMakeRange(0, 0))
diaryDate.setContentOffset(CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0), animated: false)
```

You might also need to set `UserInteractionEnabled` as YES.

Source:
https://stackoverflow.com/posts/46882570/revisions